# Is it possible to determine if function has arguments?

Tags: javascript

Is it posible to know, if my function takes vars?

For example:

```
function ada (v) {};
function dad () {};
alert(ada.hasArguments()); // true
alert(dad.hasArguments()); // false
```

Comment: Also known as [the arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. The [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of a function returns the number of declared arguments:

```
alert(ada.length); // 1
alert(dad.length); // 0
```

Comment: It's so useful to be able to find the number of declared arguments of a function in a dynamic language, and yet JavaScript's decision to call this property `length` seems odd...

Comment: Is it really that useful?

Answer (score 4):

The function's `length` property represents the number of formal parameters. Note that this is not necessarily equal to the number of *actual* parameters:

```
function foo(one, two, three) {
    return foo.length === arguments.length;
}

foo("test");
foo("test", "test", "test");
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Comment: +1 for using the correct term "formal parameters", though it should read "...not necessarily equal to the number of actual *arguments*".

Comment: "Actual argument" is redundant. "Argument" and "actual parameter" are synonymous.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments

Comment: Yes, "actual argument" would be redundant. ECMAScript doesn't use the term "actual parameter", but I do see that they do sometimes refer to arguments as parameters.